# Resizing a main image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm just trying to show a client a COMP with a full width main image (this is just a comp not a website) but I want it to resize properly.  The main area is 1124px.  I made a main image 1500 px that I put 100% of the screen.  Problem is that when I resize the screen smaller than 1500 px it does not center.  I would like the left side to begin cutting off part of the image and keep the image centered.  This is easier if you look at the link http://www.gregquinn.com/weg/webdesign9.html and begin making the screen smaller (I want the buildings and tagline to stay in the center.)  There must be an easy way to do this with overflow:hidden or something.

Comment: background-position:center?

Comment: thanks!  I knew it was something simple, it's getting really late :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey now define this css

```
    body {
    min-width: 1124px;
    }
.home-banner{
  background-repeat:center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS - background-size:cover;. It will retain the proper proportions while clipping from the edges, if the screen ratio is different than the picture ratio. It will scale with the browser window. Try various background positions, like left top, to achieve the effect that you want.

```
background-image:url(path-to-your-image);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
```

You can set the website width, or have the website display 100% width and height of the browser window using the code below. Experment, and see what functions the best.

```
html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
border:none;
background-color:#2D2D2D; /*choose a background color similar to your image*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `background-position:center;` to `.home-banner`.